# How do you add viewflow to an existing django application

Tags: django, viewflow

I have installed django-viewflow as per documentation.  I have modified settings to add viewflow module.  The workflow section of my admin pages has the process and tasks for viewflow.  That is as far as I got.  There is no viewflow.urls to include in my site.urls.  I asked in the github discussion but the only reply was "just add the viewsets to your existing url configuration" but the example is their uquickstart demo and that was not helpful as the "demo" was empty.

mysite.urls  has

```
from viewflow.contrib.auth import AuthViewset
from viewflow.urls import Application, Site, ModelViewset
...


vfsite = Site(title="Katacan", viewsets=[
    Application(
        title='KTConnector',
        icon='people',
        app_name='KTConnector',
        viewsets=[
            ModelViewset(model=User),
        ]
    ),
])
...

path('accounts/', AuthViewset(with_profile_view=False).urls),
path('vf', vfsite.urls),
```

I just need a little help on how to finish the install into my existing application.  I feel that I am close but still no banana.

Thanks

MO

Comment: Perhaps if the online viewflow demo was available as a github repo, then tips on how to integrate with existing applications with the ability to navigate to the viewflow demo pages and data from my existing application would make going from known to new much easier.

Comment: BTW going to /accounts always goes to login even after logging in successfully.

Comment: I was just thinking, the ideal would be to take the Django getting started tutorial and get that running.  Then plug in the viewflow demo app.  That would be most useful.

Comment: Continuing the thought, then a workflow to handle polls in the Django tutorial.  If I could get some help I would be happy to create a repo in github with the result.